# pycassa index with multiple values

Tags: indexing, cassandra, pycassa

I would like to query an indexed column family for multiple values. e.g.:

```
key, {key1: val1, key2: val2, key3, val1}
```

so if I query for `[val1, val2]`, then `[key1, key3]` will be returned.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The Thrift API (that Pycassa is based on) does not allow disjunctive queries, only conjunctive.

CQL does allow querying for `column IN (val1, val2)`: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/cql3/CQL.textile